# Android Firebase getting data error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

every time i try to get data from firebase Motel by Motel it just doesnt work but when i try to get just a String it works fine !! i dont know where the problem is ,this is the ChildEventListener code:

```
        refe.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

           motels.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : snap.getChildren())
    {
      Motel motel =  snap.getValue(Motel.class);
        motels.add(motel);
    }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and the Motel class code :

```
   public class Motel {
   private String name,adresse,price;
private Long stars;
private Long chambers;
private String region;

public Motel(String name, Long chambers,String adresse, String price,  String region,Long stars )
{
    this.name=name;
    this.adresse=adresse;
    this.price=price;
    this.stars=stars;
    this.chambers=chambers;
    this.region=region;

}

public String getRegion() {
    return region;
}

public void setRegion(String region) {
    this.region = region;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getChambers() {
    return chambers;
}

public void setChambers(Long chambers) {
    this.chambers = chambers;
}
```

plz help me !! i cant seem to figure out what's the problem

Comment: put error logcat

Comment: well , it is not an error , it just says application has stopped

Comment: what i am trying to do here is populate a gridView using data from firebase ! when i just get a single String like a single value not the whole motel it works fine ( i just change the list to be a list of strings instead of motels and change the adapter to normal arrayadapter<String> ) it works but when i try to get the whole motel it stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the Log so we can see the problem, but I think I already know whats happening.

The method that brings all items together is `OnDataChange` from `ValueEventListener`, meanwhile `onChildAdded` from `ChildEventListener` only take 1 at a time, and it's executed all the times needed.

Change

```
motels.clear();
for(DataSnapshot snapshot : snap.getChildren()) {
    Motel motel =  snap.getValue(Motel.class);
    motels.add(motel);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

For

```
motels.clear();
Motel motel =  dataSnapshot.getValue(Motel.class);
motels.add(motel);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: it worked thank you =) and sorry i am kinda new to asking questions , still don't know how to ask the right way